# Nginx letsencrypt certbot ssl page will not load over https but will load over http

Tags: networking, nginx, ssl, firewall, debian-stretch

I am trying to set up a digital ocean server using this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04

The site is served just fine over HTTP but will not load from https.
(will not load references this chrome error)

```
This site can’t be reached kronoswebsolutions.com took too long to respond.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

As advised I did check the firewall previous to posting but here is the output of my ufw. I do not have a firewall enabled on my digital ocean droplet web gui.

```
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW       *************             
22                         ALLOW       *************             
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

```
Here is the results of nmap from my local machine using the ip of my server...

nmap -Pn -p 443 IPADDRESS
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-05-07 23:46 MDT
Nmap scan report for IPADDRESS
Host is up.

PORT    STATE    SERVICE
443/tcp filtered https
```

I am using Debian stretch rather than Ubuntu.

Comment: "Will not load" is, to put it mildly, an uninformative problem description.

Comment: Is this still to vague or are the edits I provided any help?

Comment: It's understandable now, but you really do need to do what it advised: check the firewall.

Comment: I posted the ufw rules of my server

Comment: The ufw rules look fine. But if you disable ufw and reboot, can you then get in?

Comment: Yes I can get in

Comment: So... it's a firewall problem.  You can rip out everything about certbot, gunicorn, and nginx config from your question, then.

Comment: Now re-enable ufw and check if you can still get in.

Comment: I can still get into the server when I disable ufw and reboot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was definitely a firewall issue.
I used this to reset my firewalls settings in iptables then set ufw up again and it is working.

First, set the default policies for each of the built-in chains to ACCEPT. The main reason to do this is to ensure that you won't be locked out from your server via SSH:

```
$ sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Then flush the nat and mangle tables, flush all chains (-F), and delete all non-default chains (-X):

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -F
$ sudo iptables -t mangle -F
$ sudo iptables -F
$ sudo iptables -X
```

Then re enable ufw

```
$ sudo ufw enable
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer as the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue after following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04) and it turns out that it misses this piece of code that you have to add to your site's nginx.conf:

```
listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/{{ domain }}/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/{{ domain }}/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
```